# How do you apply flex to child components of a grid in material-ui?

Tags: css, flexbox

Rather than applying a margin to every child, is there a flex way to do this?

```
        <Grid item xs={12} xl={4} className={classes.paper}>
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
          <TextField style={{margin: "8px"}} id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
        </Grid>
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ik8gz?file=/demo.tsx

How do I apply Justify-Content to the children?

Comment: This is a css/flexbox question that is not related at all to material-ui (unless you are looking for a material-ui solution, which will probably involve another nested Grid)

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Sorry, I removed the material-ui tag. I have added a code sand box, I want the top two grids to look like the bottom grid but use flex instead of margin.

Comment: I had an assumption that flex was on by default for material-ui elements. I used style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap", justifyContent: "space-around" }} so assumption was my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Grid` for `TextField` and use `spacing` to set margin:

```
<Grid container spacing={4} justify="center">
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} xl={4}>
    <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Outlined" variant="outlined" />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `justify-content` applied, too.

Answer (score 1):

Add the margin style to every `<Textfield />` child would be fine

You can optionally achieve this via nesting selector of className

```
import { Grid, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  paper: {
    "& .MuiTextField-root": {
      margin: 8
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: This is a better solution, thank you. If i cant get Justify-Content to work ill go with this.